# Google Custom search engine

Tags: asp.net

just want to know is it possible to add Google Search Engine in my site which is using localhost to run. I'm using asp.net. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No very easily.  Google closed their web service API and now only offers a javascript version.  Check out bing.com/developer if you want to integrate a comparable search solution with a real API available to you.